# Why is my jQuery widget returning 'object is not a function'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

I'm trying to create a 2 column autocomplete. I theory this code should be correct, but I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` and I don't know why.

Can anyone see why I'm getting this error? [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMfb8/) - to reproduce the error, type at least two characters into the text field starting with `mo`.

*PS. There is a bug in jsFiddle. If you click Update after saving the first time, you will get an 403 forbidden. Hopefully they'll fix this asap.*

**UPDATE**
So I've done some debugging. Switching from `jquery.min.js` to `jquery.js` shows that jQuery actually fails on the `each`:

> TypeError: obj is undefined
>   length = obj.length,

So by doing this:

```
var stores = items.stores;
console.log(stores.toSource());
```

you will get a `TypeError: stores is undefined`

But if you do this:

```
$.each( items, function( index, item ) {
  console.log(item.toSource());
});
```

it will output

```
// Stores
({0:{id:"4058", name:"Moods"...}, 1:{id:"4059", name:"Moody"...}, label:(void 0), value:(void 0)})  

// Brands
({0:{id:"4673", name:"Moods"...}, 1:{id:"4674", name:"MOOKS"...}, label:(void 0), value:(void 0)})
```

**UPDATE 2**
It seems that `response(data);` removes named parameters in the JSON object.
If you do this:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.stores.toSource()); // <-- This works
    response(data); // But after this, it no longer works
}
```

Now you can dot his:

```
console.log(data[0].toSource());
```

code:

```
var data = 
  {"stores":[
      {"id":"4058","name":"Mo-shu","city":"Oslo","fk_countryID":"NO"},
      {"id":"4059","name":"Mood","city":"Oslo","fk_countryID":"NO"}
  ],
  "brands":[
      {"id":"4673","name":"Moods"},
      {"id":"4674","name":"MOOKS"}
  ]
}    


$.widget( "custom.searchAutocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this;
        ul.addClass('searchAutocomplete');
        ul.append('<li class="stores left"></li>');
        ul.append('<li class="brands left"><li>');

        $.each( items.stores, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItem( ul.find('.stores' ), item, 'store' );
        });

        $.each( items.brands, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItem( ul.find('.brands' ), item,'brand' );
        });

    },
    _renderItem: function( li, item, type) {
        var listItem = $('<div />');

        listItem.data('ui-autocomplete-item', item );

        if(type == 'store') {
            listItem.append( "<a>"+ item.name + "<br /><span class='address'>Street name here</span></a>" );
        } else {
            listItem.append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>');
        }

        listItem.appendTo( li ); 
        return listItem;
    }
});

$('#search-box').searchAutocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: data,
  select: function(e, ui){
     $(this).val(ui.item.name);
     return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think there is problem with this code, but since you having a custom object type and are trying to create custom widget... so some function of autocomplete which does not take object of this type(it takes a default object of format having a `label` and `value`) is causing problem... try defining rest autocomplete options as well, like `select`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "source" parameter only accepts 3 types of input - refer to http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source to see that the format you give it is not appropriate. I've done a little research and this works:

```
$('#search-box').searchAutocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: function(request,response)
    {
        response(data);
    }
});
```

Everything else is about debugging your extending methods.

I've updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PMfb8/2/

Comment: This works in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PMfb8/2/ - but when using `$.ajax`, the response callback still removes the named attributes.